# How to know the number of days until today in this year

Tags: c#, days

I want to know the number of days from january 1st to today.

If today is January 10th, then `numOfDays=10`, if today is February 1st then `numOfDays=32`.

How can I get the total no of days? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime`'s `DayOfYear` property.

```
int dayOfYear = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
```

Comment: How can I get the number from datetimepicker date.??

Comment: @CenBan `dtp.Value.DayOfYear`

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime.DayOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx) is exactly what you want.

To find out the day of year for today:

```
var days = DateTime.Today.DayOfYear;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
int currDayOfYear = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
```

Answer (score -1):

This shows how to do it.  Step by step, use DateTime.Now to get a DateTime object representing the current date/time.  Then use the DateTime.DayOfYear property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx

public int DayOfYear { get; }

Property Value
Type: System.Int32
The day of the year, expressed as a value between 1 and 366.

Datetime.Now explained:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx